# ColdFusion client variables

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have an issue with client variables in ColdFusion 10. When I create client variables in one page it is effecting that page only and I am not able to access the variables in another page in my application. Here is code from Application.cfc:

```
this.Name = "test";
this.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,0,0);
this.ClientManagement= "yes";
this.ClientStorage = "clientstorage";
this.SessionManagement = true;
this.SessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan( 0, 0, 20, 0 );
this.SetClientCookies = "yes";
this.SetDomainCookies = "no";
this.ScriptProtect = "all";
```

Comment: Is it because your application is set to time out every request? I'm not sure how that impacts client variables, though.

Comment: Do you have a datasource named `clientstorage`? Because you are setting `this.ClientStorage = "clientstorage";`  Are you seeing updates to that database?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on a site and fixed it by using setdomaincookies="yes"